# Windows 7: View column headers in Windows Explorer when in icon view

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, sorting

In windows 7 is there a way to view the column headers in Windows Explorer when you are in icon view?  When in details view you get a list of column headers that makes it easy to filter or sort by your data.  Is there a way to enable the column headers when in icon view?  I’ve been running Windows 7 on my main machine since RC1 so it’s been about a year and a half since I used Vista but I can almost swear that this was a feature in Vista.  I can’t seem to find a way to do it in Windows 7. I find it useful when viewing folders with both photos and videos to be able to filter/sort by one type or another.  If anyone out there knows how to do it pleas let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: I done some more research and it appears that Microsoft has intentionally removed this feature but you can use QTTAbBar to restore this feature.  Here is a screen print of it working for me  http://bit.ly/EnableColumnHeadersInWin7

Answer (score 1):

I done some more research and it appears that Microsoft has intentionally removed this feature but you can use QTTAbBar to restore this feature.  Here is a [screen print of it working for me](https://docs.google.com/document/edit?id=1Gp0JpN8L-GnlAhcOUUA_-NFxmsesLNT3vIjj7vNs-VQ&hl=en&pli=1).